# Why did Artisan Schedule ignore "withoutOverlapping"?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cron, laravel-artisan

In my Laravel Kernel I have the following schedule function:

```
   $schedule->command('import:currencyrate')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping(1)->emailOutputOnFailure('contact@website.com');
    $schedule->command('import:token_data')->everyFiveMinutes()->withoutOverlapping(1)->emailOutputOnFailure('contact@website.com');
    $schedule->command('import:nft_data')->everyTenMinutes()->withoutOverlapping(1);
```

This usually works without any issues for the last year. But for the last few days, my server crashes 1-2 times a day, due to tasks that don't complete & overlap:

[image]

How is this possible? I use withoutOverlapping, shouldn't that stop the same task to run multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have written `->withoutOverlapping(1)` that means after 1 min of lock time your task will run again. [Click here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps)  to see the laravel documentation. Try `->withoutOverlapping()` and check.